# Initialize instance of internal discriminated union from F# to C#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I have a discriminated union type exported via a dll from F# to be used in C#:

```
type Argument =
  | IntValue
  | FloatValue
  | BoolValue of bool
```

In C# I can initialize something like `Argument.NewBoolValue(true)`, but the other two types `IntValue` and `FloatValue` are not type generated via the F# compiler and hence marked as internal, is there a way to initialize them in C#?

Comment: There should be a `Argument.IntValue` and `Argument.FloatValue` `static` properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the discriminated union case doesn't have any payload, there is no `NewXXX` method generated. Because all instances of such union case will be the same and there is no need in creation function. So use staic properties instead

```
Argument.IntValue
Argument.FloatValue
```

Internally these properties just return singleton instance of corresponding usecase:

```
internal static readonly Argument _unique_IntValue = new _IntValue();

public static Argument IntValue => _unique_IntValue;
```

More interesting details can be observed [in this decompiled snippet](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgPgLgngBwKYAICCAnA5gVwLZIB2MKAvALABQKKUKAksQGoCGwOSVNdAYsAPYsYrdp2q0UAIX79gIjin5gUAIxnAqQA===).